# JS ddsclick not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i have the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<%:ResolveUrl("~/Content/JS/jquery.ddslick.min.js")%>" ></script>
```

and

```
 $(function () {
        var dropdownlist = [
            {
                text: "RO",
                value: 1,
                imageSrc: "~/Images/icon-romanian-flag.png"
            },
            {
                text: "EN",
                value: 2,
                imageSrc: "~/Images/icon-english-flag.png"
            }
        ];

        $("#dropd").ddslick({
            data: dropdownlist,
            width: 200,
            imagePosition: "Left"
        });
    });
```

and

```
<div id="dropd"></div>
```

I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ddslick is not a function

I am trying to build a dropdownlist with two values for two languages.

Comment: inspect your browser and see if "jquery.ddslick.min.js" get loaded or not. OR try with some local copy of "jquery.ddslick.min.js"

Comment: the file is loaded. it appears in browser's sources

Answer (score 1):

So I had the same problem and it was because of the order of loading the javascript files, in my case since I am using angular.js and jquery, I had to load these .js files first, load the ddslick.min.js second, and then my controller.js file.

Try rearranging the javascripts loading.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Its mostly because the script file has not be loaded.
Try using **this**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40036711/Scripts/jquery.ddslick.min.js"></script>
```

Instead of:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%:ResolveUrl("~/Content/JS/jquery.ddslick.min.js")%>" ></script>
```

Comment: the live demo site is having the same issue. dropbox unreachable.

Comment: May be,you should save it in your local server and use it.

Comment: thanks for your help guys, but i saved local both jquery-1.8.2 and ddslick and it still says same thing. both files are loaded i checked the browser